# Fusing absolute pose data

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-localization, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I understand, in the robot_localization state estimation node, the differential parameter should be set to *false* if sensor contains  absolute pose information. However, in [this](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/Preparing%20Your%20Sensor%20Data) robot_localization tutorial, in section 2.1.1, it's stated that "If fusing absolute pose data (position or rotation), you will most likely want to set the sensor's *differential* parameter to *true*. "

Assuming that absolute position and/or orientation information is coming from only one source, is there any reason that we should set the differential parameter to *true*?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199995/fusing-absolute-pose-data/) by [Shokoofeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1890/shokoofeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only reason to set the `differential` parameter to *true* if you only have one source of pose and/or orientation data is to ensure that the output of the state estimate starts at 0. For example, if your *input* pose data starts at (10, 23), then using the differential parameter will make sure the *output* position still starts at (0, 0). This is actually more important for orientation from IMUs, as the orientation is probably not going to align with your world frame (i.e., it will not start at 0).

In any case, the intended use for the differential parameter was to allow for multiple independent measurements of absolute pose/orientation data. I should clarify this in the tutorial.

One exception: GPS data or measurements of absolute position estimates resulting from, for example, landmark observations should also *not* be fused differentially.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-03-10**:
Update on this: a forthcoming version will add a *xxx_relative* parameter, which can be used to fuse data absolutely (i.e., non-differentially), but will still allow it to start at 0.